# Check checkbox whose values are stored in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function, where I am currently pre-selecting all checkboxes:

```
function setupModuleSelection(selectedModules, preSelected) {
    // TODO: preSelected not used
    $('#my-table > tbody > tr > td.module_id > input[type="checkbox"]')
        .prop('checked', true);
}
```

Where `preSelected = ['module-001', 'module-003', 'module-027']` (for example):

The table is:

```
<tr>
...
<td class="module_id"><input type="checkbox" name="module_id" value="module-027"></td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to activate the checkboxes by filtering on the `module_id`, as provided by the `preSelected` array. How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: @Ramanlfc thats not true.

Comment: what is `td.module_id` in your jquery selection?

Comment: @Azzi: sorry Azzi, that slipped my copy-paste. Added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attribute-value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as follow

```
var preSelected = ['module-001', 'module-003', 'module-027'];

var selector = ':checkbox[value="' + preSelected.join('"], :checkbox[value="') + '"]';
$(selector).prop('checked', true);
```

The value of `selector` will be

```
:checkbox[value="module-001"], :checkbox[value="module-003"], :checkbox[value="module-027"]
```

And passing this string to the jQuery object will select all the required checkboxes.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

var selector = ':checkbox[value="' + vowels.join('"], :checkbox[value="') + '"]';
console.log(selector);
$(selector).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="aa" value="a" /> A
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" value="b" /> B
<input type="checkbox" name="Cc" value="c" /> C
<input type="checkbox" name="dd" value="d" /> D
<input type="checkbox" name="ee" value="e" /> E
<input type="checkbox" name="ff" value="f" /> F
<input type="checkbox" name="ii" value="i" /> I
```

Comment: Mmm, the module_id is not in the name, but in the value in my case (django generated: CheckBoxColumn from django_tables2)

Comment: Ok, I get it, but, and this might be just me not being that deep into jQuery: is  such a (potentially) huge selector performant? Wouldn't it be faster (and clearer) to do a `forEach` as in void's answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
preSelected = ['module-001', 'module-003', 'module-027'];

[].forEach.call(preSelected, function(val){

    $("#my-table input[type='checkbox'][value='"+val+"']").prop('checked', true);

});
```

You can use something like this, selecting the `input` based on the value.

Comment: Ok, I just knew that you can call checkbox value like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can join array values to generate attribute equals selector:

```
$('#my-table > tbody > tr > td.module_id > input[type="checkbox"][value="' + preSelected .join('"],[value="') + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```